# Escaping Discord subset of markdown

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I'm trying to escape the subset of markdown that Discord supports (`*`, `_`, `` ` ``, `~`).
Characters that are already escaped should not have additional backslashes added.
This is what I have:

```js
function escapeMarkdown(text) {
 return text.replace(/([^\\]|^|\*|_|`|~)(\*|_|`|~)/g, '$1\\$2');
}

console.log(escapeMarkdown('*test* _string_ ~please~ `ignore` *_`~kthx \*  \\~'));
```

This works fine, minus the fact that multiple markdown characters against each other will not all be escaped. I'm not sure how to expand this to allow for that, without making the expression absurdly complicated.

Comment: If a character already has a backslash in front of it, that doesn't necessarily mean it's escaped, e.g. `\\~`

Comment: @qxz You are entirely correct.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest unescaping any already-escaped characters, then escaping everything again:

```js
function escapeMarkdown(text) {
  var unescaped = text.replace(/\\(\*|_|`|~|\\)/g, '$1'); // unescape any "backslashed" character
  var escaped = unescaped.replace(/(\*|_|`|~|\\)/g, '\\$1'); // escape *, _, `, ~, \
  return escaped;
}

var str = '*test* _string_ ~please~ `ignore` *_`~kthx \*  \\~ C:\\path\\to\\file';
console.log("Original:");
console.log(str);
console.log("Escaped:");
console.log(escapeMarkdown(str));
```

Comment: This is actually very close to what I ended up coming up with myself and am currently using, but it isn't without side-effects. It does solve the problem of existing double-escapes on markdown characters not being escaped, but it also completely eliminates existing backslashes from the string. If the string is supposed to contain a raw backslash (like Windows paths) with \\, it'll be entirely gone from the result.

Comment: Edited the first regex to only unescape the 5 special chars.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a markdown escape function for my NodeJS discord bot recently, here's the code I used.

```js
var markdownEscape = function(text) {
   return text.replace(/((\_|\*|\~|\`|\|){2})/g, '\\$1');
};

console.log(markdownEscape('||some spoiler text||'));
```

It'll add a backslash before any of the characters in the regular expression if there is 2 of them.

Comment: I translated this to PHP: `preg_replace("/((\_|\*|\~|\`|\|){2})/", '\\\\$1', $txt);`

Comment: Note that this won't work for *italics*, since there is only one asterisk needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is in ruby, not js, but this can be trivially translated to JS, it escapes all known discord special characters (+ prevent previews with links)

```rb
  def escape(str)
    # \ -> \\
    str = str.gsub("\\") { "\\\\" }
    # - -> \_
    str = str.gsub('_') { "\\_" }
    # * -> \*
    str = str.gsub('*') { "\\*" }
    # ~ -> \~
    str = str.gsub('~') { "\\~" }
    # ` -> \`
    str = str.gsub('`') { '\\`' }
    # | -> \|
    str = str.gsub('|') { '\\|' }
    # urls without previews
    str = str.gsub(/https?:\/\/[\S]+/) { |url| "<#{url}>" }

    str
  end
```

(I'm posting this here as I'm sure it could help future readers and this seems to be the only place talking about this issue)

And here is a string full of Discord formatting things as a bonus:

````
Italics *italics* or _italics_
Underline italics __*underline italics*__
Bold **bold**
Underline bold __**underline bold**__
Bold Italic ***bold italics***
underline bold italics __***underline bold italics***__
Underline __underline__
Strikethrough  ~~Strikethrough~~
Link https://google.com https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex
Code: `inline`

```
block
```

```ruby
block with language
```

Spoiler: ||spoiler||
````